# C# How to send file to discord webhook and get file link?

Tags: c#, discord, webhooks

Hello i want send a file to my discord webhook address and get that sent file's link for download it.

I know sending file to webhook is possible but i want get this file's download link. Is it possible?

I have this code I just need that test.txt's download link:

```
            string Webhook_link = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/959919400243326976/uGiJbuiddUbEGovMgKtx2Z-byUX7jvhCcqgs5-IBYq1pAIrKlpnyVvjrMicJjS9tC_-a";
            string FilePath = @"C:\Users\sadettin\Desktop\test.txt";

            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                var file_bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
                form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(file_bytes, 0, file_bytes.Length), "Document", "file.txt");
                httpClient.PostAsync(Webhook_link, form).Wait();
                httpClient.Dispose();
            }
```

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60931626/how-do-i-send-files-in-discord-webhook

Comment: @mrbean Hello there is not problem with sending files to webhook address problem is i need get and write sent file's link in console like Console.Write(<Sent file's Link>);

Answer (score 0):

Discord webhooks support 2 query string parameters:

- `wait` - Waits for server confirmation of message send before response, and returns the created message body
- `thread_id` - Send a message to the specified thread within a webhook's channel. The thread will automatically be unarchived.

In this instance, the one we want is `wait`. So with your example link of `https://discord.com/api/webhooks/959919400243326976/uGiJbuiddUbEGovMgKtx2Z-byUX7jvhCcqgs5-IBYq1pAIrKlpnyVvjrMicJjS9tC_-a`, you'd made a request to `https://discord.com/api/webhooks/959919400243326976/uGiJbuiddUbEGovMgKtx2Z-byUX7jvhCcqgs5-IBYq1pAIrKlpnyVvjrMicJjS9tC_-a?wait=true`. This then returns [message](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#message-object) object on completion.

Example code:

```cs
public static async void Example()
{
    string Webhook_link = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/959919400243326976/uGiJbuiddUbEGovMgKtx2Z-byUX7jvhCcqgs5-IBYq1pAIrKlpnyVvjrMicJjS9tC_-a?wait=true";
    string FilePath = @"C:\Users\sadettin\Desktop\test.txt";

    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        var file_bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
        form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(file_bytes, 0, file_bytes.Length), "Document", "file.txt");
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(Webhook_link, form))
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            string json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Message? msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(json);
            if (msg == null)
            {
                // Handle failed to read output
            }
            else if (msg.Attachments.Count == 0)
            {
                // Failed to get attachment
            }
            else
            {
                Message.AttachmentObj attachment = msg.Attachments[0];
                Console.WriteLine(attachment.Url);
            }
        }
        // Removed `httpClient.Dispose()` due to the `using` statement already handling that
    }
}

public class Message
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string? Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public int? Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("content")]
    public string? Content { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("channel_id")]
    public string? ChannelId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("author")]
    public AuthorObj? Author { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("attachments")]
    public List<AttachmentObj> Attachments { get; } = new();

    [JsonProperty("pinned")]
    public bool? Pinned { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("mention_everyone")]
    public bool? MentionEveryone { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tts")]
    public bool? Tts { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    public DateTime? Timestamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("flags")]
    public int? Flags { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("webhook_id")]
    public string? WebhookId { get; set; }

    public class AttachmentObj
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string? Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("filename")]
        public string? Filename { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("size")]
        public int? Size { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("url")]
        public string? Url { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("proxy_url")]
        public string? ProxyUrl { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string? Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("content_type")]
        public string? ContentType { get; set; }
    }

    public class AuthorObj
    {
        [JsonProperty("bot")]
        public bool? Bot { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string? Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("username")]
        public string? Username { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("avatar")]
        public string? Avatar { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("discriminator")]
        public string? Discriminator { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This uses [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) to parse the `Message` json result, which you can then pull the `Attachment` from.