# Create Discord Event for Stage Channel with webhook using C#

Tags: c#, discord

I've managed to post to Discord using webhook and C# using code found here on StackOverflow, but I'd also like to be able to create an Scheduled Event for a Stage Channel. Has anyone done this or are able to help me out?

Discord API Doc: https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild-scheduled-event#create-guild-scheduled-event

````
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71721198/c-sharp-how-to-send-file-to-discord-webhook-and-get-file-link
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53982148/how-to-patch-data-using-system-net-http
//https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#edit-webhook-message
public static class HttpClientExtensions
{
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PatchAsync(this HttpClient client, Uri requestUri, HttpContent iContent)
    {
        var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, requestUri)
        {
            Content = iContent
        };
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
        try
        {
            response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException e)
        {
        }

        return response;
    }
}

public class CPHInline
{
    string webhookLink = "[webhook-url-goes-here]";
    public bool Execute()
    {
        SendMsg();
        return true;
    }

    public async void SendMsg()
    {
        string FilePath = CPH.GetGlobalVar<string>("screenshotFileFull");
        string StreamTitle = CPH.GetGlobalVar<string>("myStreamTitle");
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            var file_bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath);
            form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(file_bytes, 0, file_bytes.Length), "Image", "file.png");
            form.Add(new StringContent("# " + StreamTitle), "content");
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(webhookLink + "?wait=true", form))
            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
            {
                string json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Message? msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(json);
                CPH.SendMessage(msg.Id, true);
                CPH.SetGlobalVar("dcMsgId", msg.Id, true);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Message
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public string? Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public int? Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("content")]
        public string? Content { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("channel_id")]
        public string? ChannelId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("author")]
        public AuthorObj? Author { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("attachments")]
        public List<AttachmentObj> Attachments { get; } = new();

        [JsonProperty("pinned")]
        public bool? Pinned { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("mention_everyone")]
        public bool? MentionEveryone { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("tts")]
        public bool? Tts { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
        public DateTime? Timestamp { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("flags")]
        public int? Flags { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("webhook_id")]
        public string? WebhookId { get; set; }

        public class AttachmentObj
        {
            [JsonProperty("id")]
            public string? Id { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("filename")]
            public string? Filename { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("size")]
            public int? Size { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("url")]
            public string? Url { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("proxy_url")]
            public string? ProxyUrl { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("description")]
            public string? Description { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("content_type")]
            public string? ContentType { get; set; }
        }

        public class AuthorObj
        {
            [JsonProperty("bot")]
            public bool? Bot { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("id")]
            public string? Id { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("username")]
            public string? Username { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("avatar")]
            public string? Avatar { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("discriminator")]
            public string? Discriminator { get; set; }
        }
    }
}```
````